# Is there a supervisor for python 3?

Tags: python, supervisord

I want to use supervisor to run celery in production, but I am using python 3 instead of python 2.  Is there a supervisor that supports python 3?

Also, is it possible to use python 2 to run supervisor for my python 3 code for celery?

Comment: You could consider installing Python 2 and 3 alongside each other to let supervisor start / manage applications written in Python 3. It's not ideal but may be the best solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`supervisord` is just process manager, fact that itself uses python2 does not mean it can't run python3 application.

Just put your application in virtualenv created with python3.

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 myvenv
```

Activate that environment and install your app into it with celery as well. And in supervisor you will use full path to celery from inside that virtualenv.

e.g. I created my python3 virtualenv in `/home/beezz/myvenv` then `celery` will be located at `/home/beezz/myenv/bin/celery`

And here is [virtualenv's documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html). In general it's good practice to keep applications in separate virtual environments.

If you are not tied to `supervisord` somehow, [circus](http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is also nice process manager with some cool features and it's python3 ready.

Comment: For anyone looking to use circus check this out http://aameer.github.io/circus-as-an-alternative-to-supervisor/

Comment: supervisor docs states that it will NOT run under python3 though!  http://supervisord.org/introduction.html#platform-requirements

Comment: They've change their mind, and are implementing python3 support https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor#supported-platforms

Comment: why not https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay?